# place multiple images in particular position where user wants

Tags: javascript, jsp

i m trying this code .. but i have try in java and jsp so i am not getting the proper idea how to place it?

```
enter code here

<html>
<head>
<title>Using JSTL Functions</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:set var="string1" value="This is first String."/>
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:replace(string1, 
                                'first', 'second')}" />

<p>Final String : ${string2}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to do here.

Comment: i have designed one text field using jsp.. i want to place number of images there where i want means text and images should be there